# Unable to upload training data for AutoML entity extraction NLP

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I am able to upload the test data from the [Quickstart example](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/entity-analysis/docs/quickstart))  but when I try and upload data from my own google cloud storage I get

```
"Error: Cannot find the referenced file: in request."
```

I tried taking the data from the quick start that I know works and putting it on my own google cloud storage and uploading it from there and I get the same thing.

I am able to see all of the files when I browse for objects and I am able to see it all just fine. I even tried making the files public to all users thinking maybe it was a permissions thing but it doesn't appear to be that either.

Any advice?